# Margin-left:auto not working in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, margin

Hi I am trying to center my main content part which is the gray portion.  It is centered in Mozilla, but not IE (I wish IE would be removed from all computers).  It is the margin-left:auto that isn't working.  Can someone please help me fix this issue?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
<div style="background-color:gray; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:1000px; height:1000px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:-10px;">
<p style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:500px; background-color:red; text-align:center">This is a test.</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add doctype on first line of your page!
  
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: 1) dont forget to accept answer  2) you should read this: http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/doctype-declaration.htm

Comment: Also make sure you have NOTHING before the doctype, no HTML comments <!-- --> or even white space